# Render URL is not able to fetch the different routing pages of backend app?

Tags: node.js

Recently i hosted my backend node app on render the deployment was successful as the log is showing connected to mongo but when i am using the render url in thunder client to fetch different routing pages like OrderData,DisplayData can anyone help me regarding this?

i have included the cors origin fow and process.env.port in index.js file but still it is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.